# deploy Large amount of data in setup

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, installation

I have a VB.NET 2008 desktop application.  My app needs large amounts of data (~4GB) to work.  These include several files types including access databases and DBF files and text files etc.  These are files I cannot change since my app is actually an UI for another program which the user prepares data files (the large number of different files) for.  Visusl studio doesn't let me build large installer due to 2GB memory limit and the /GB switch on boot file doesn't work for me.  Are there any other options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) or [innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#limits) installers (they don't impose such limits, afaik).

Alternatively, you could place large files separately and either use some script/small gui wrapper which would copy/link them or even leave it to user. As another option, you could prompt for resource file location from your GUI program when it is started for the first time.

One more option is to build multi-volume installer.

Comment: thanks barti_ddu.  I am actually using the gui wrapper technique but my client just wants a click once install as the end users are field crew and,to put it mildly, 'technology challenged'.  Is there a way I can add a post install script along with the installer that will run at the end and copy files and directories to respective folders on the users machine ?

Comment: @captonssj: yes, you can (it is called *custom action* in vc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx); also take a look at nsis and innosetup, they both are highly scriptable, and innosetup comes with gui wizard so you can create installer in minutes without any prior knowledge.

Comment: Thanks again.  Will try these options.